# ImageIO.read unable to find .png-file

Tags: java, embedded-resource, javax.imageio

sorry if this has been asked quite a few times, I'm new here.
I've used three different approaches to get a file to be loaded and nothing worked:

Using Toolkit:

```
    Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("apple.png"));
```

Using a File:

```
    BufferedImage img = null;
    try {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File("apple.png"));
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Using a FileInputStream:

```
    Path path=Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath().normalize();
    String dir=path.toFile().getAbsolutePath()+"\\resources\\apple.png";
    BufferedImage image = null;
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream(dir));
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**path** and **dir** are working fine getting me an absolute path but I alway end up with **image = null**.

/edit:
@DuncG: I don't get an exception so there's no stacktrace to post, sorry. `new File("apple.png").exists()` evaluates to `false`.
@Harald_K: It is a normal .png image-file I have on my local system. It is located in `src/main/resources/apple.png`.

Comment: Add stack trace / error details to your question and the result of calling `new File("apple.png").exists()` / `new File(dir).exists()` before `ImageIO.read`

Comment: Is your PNG file a resource (part of your application bundle) or a normal file (something found in the user's file system)? If it's a resource, use `getResource` or `getResourceAsStream`. Otherwise, use `new File`. Where is it located? All of the above does indeed work, as long as you get the correct path to your resource or file.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that your program is NOT able to find the required file and then further read it as an Image. This is a common recurring problem statement in any modern-day app where a required resource is NOT found, halting subsequent operations.
I would suggest writing a common piece of code to always locate such files/resources in your project dir just by giving the filename and returning the path.

```
@Slf4j
public class PathFinder {

private static Path filepath;

public static Path getFilePathForFile(String filename) {
  log.info("Looking for filepath for given filename: ".concat(filename));
    try {
     filepath = Files.walk(Paths.get("."))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()).stream()
                .filter(file -> !Files.isDirectory(file) && 
               file.getFileName().toString().startsWith(filename))
                .findFirst().get();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
    log.error(exception.getMessage());
    } return filepath;
  }
}
```

Now you can easily use the above Pathfinder utility class to look for any given file and further operate on it as shown below:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(PathFinder.getFilePathForFile("apple.png")
                                           .toFile());
```